# JMS Body content filter

Tags: filter, jms, message, publisher, subscriber

I m working on JMS. I create a TextMessage and append some text("Hello World") to it. Now, I want to filter the messages based on the words/content("Hello") in the body of the message.

I tried using selector, but I think it only filter properties in header.

Can, this filter occur?

Thanks and Regards.